# Remove values from a string SAS

Tags: sas

I have this column which i would wish to remain only the names and wish to remove everything after the ( s. May i know how could i achieve this?

```
Name                 Age
James                12
John (funny)         11
Jonathan             10
Alisa (134 cm)       12
Merlin (cheerful)    12
Jessica (hopeful)    12
Ali (quiet)          13
```

I have tried using functions such as compress but it still didnt work

```
data output; 
    length Name $30.;

    infile datalines dlm=','; 
    input Name$ Age;
    new = compress(name, '()'); 
    datalines; 
James,12
John (funny),11
Jonathan,10
Alisa (134 cm),12
Merlin (cheerful),12
Jessica (hopeful),12
Ali (quiet),13
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating based on Tom's suggestion:

Use `scan()` and treat `(` as a delimiter. This will pull all text before the first `(`.

```
new = scan(name, 1, '(', 'T')
```

The `T` option trims any trailing blanks.

Comment: Just use SCAN() with '(' as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl regular expression patterns to replace parenthetical content with 'nothing'

```
name = prxchange ('s/\(.*?\)//', -1, name);
```